# Refresh WFS Layer in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, wfs, refresh

I'm working with a GeoServer WFS in QGIS 3.4. If I open two parallel projects with the WFS layer included and successfully change some date over WFS-T in one project, I can't get the new changes in the other. Only after reopen the project or reimport the WFS layer will show the changes.

Is there an option to refresh the WFS layer after zoom and pan?

I can't find any cache options for a WFS layer.

Comment: Have you tried F5?

Comment: Hi @Erik, thanks for your hint! F5 works perfect. But i'm wondering why it's not refreshing automatic when zoom and pan.